# Prove that $3$ divides $n^2 + n$ iff $n$ mod $3$ $\neq 1$

Tags: proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that 
$3$ divides $n^2 + n$ iff  $n$ mod $3$ $\neq 1$ .
I already tried it with proving a double implication, but I did not succeed. A tip or kickstart would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following cases:

- $n\equiv0\pmod3 \implies n^2+n\equiv0^2+0\equiv0\pmod3$
- $n\equiv1\pmod3 \implies n^2+n\equiv1^2+1\equiv2\pmod3$
- $n\equiv2\pmod3 \implies n^2+n\equiv2^2+2\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So the proof would be 'by cases' ?

Comment: Well, you can construct the proof in any way you like, but the fact of the matter is that $n\not\equiv1\pmod3 \iff n\equiv0,2\pmod3$. You're welcome BTW :)

Answer (score 0):

Just factor $n^{2}+n$ and it becomes quite obvious